# Trigger not updating tsvector on insert/update

Tags: postgresql, triggers, full-text-search

I'm trying to munge data from a few columns across a few tables to make it full-text searchable, but I'm not having much luck.

Here's my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_customer_save_udpate_tsv() RETURNS trigger AS $$ 
declare 
   tsv_text text; 
begin 
SELECT string_agg(cust_text.text, ' ') as agg_text into tsv_text 
FROM (SELECT concat("name", ' ', "phone") as text 
   FROM "Customers" 
   where "id" = NEW.id 
   UNION 
   SELECT concat("firstName", ' ', "lastName", ' ', "phone", ' ', "email") as text 
   FROM "Contacts" 
   where "customerId" = NEW.id 
   UNION 
   SELECT concat("streetLine1", ' ', "city", ' ', "state", ' ', "zip") as text 
   FROM "Addresses" 
   where "customerId" = NEW.id) cust_text; 
NEW.tsv := to_tsvector(coalesce(tsv_text,'')); 
return NEW; 
end 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cust_tsv_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON "Customers" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_customer_save_udpate_tsv();
```

However, the "Customers".tsv column is blank after inserts/updates.

When I run the bulk of the function manually, it works as expected.

```
DO $$ 
declare 
   tsv_text text; 
begin 
SELECT string_agg(cust_text.text, ' ') as agg_text into tsv_text 
FROM (SELECT concat("name", ' ', "phone") as text 
   FROM "Customers" 
   where "id" = 17 
   UNION 
   SELECT concat("firstName", ' ', "lastName", ' ', "phone", ' ', "email") as text 
   FROM "Contacts" 
   where "customerId" = 17
   UNION 
   SELECT concat("streetLine1", ' ', "city", ' ', "state", ' ', "zip") as text 
   FROM "Addresses" 
   where "customerId" = 17) cust_text; 

   UPDATE "Customers"
   SET tsv = to_tsvector(coalesce(tsv_text, ''))
   WHERE "id" = 17;
end 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm fairly new to postgres. What am I missing?

Comment: your code looks well. Try to use RAISE NOTICE to debug: 1. your trigger is really executed, 2. The result of query is not empty, 3. result of to_tsvector is not empty. Some is wrong, but hard to fix it on first shot. Should to start somewhere - so break your problem to smaller pieces and search step by step what is wrong.

Comment: How do you know that "Customers".tsv is blank? What client are you using to inspect the value?

Comment: @Patrick I run a select and check the field values..

Comment: @PavelStehule I did go about adding `RAISE NOTICE` to my function. However, I do not know how to see the messages when my app is inserting/updating.

Comment: Run your INSERTs/UPDATEs from console - psql

Comment: Well, I feel a bit sheepish. My trigger is set to run BEFORE insert or update. I am attempting to select a record that hasn't been inserted. I naively tried to switch it to AFTER. Then the tsv column wasn't set. Then I fired an update in my trigger and went into an infinite loop. Then i realized I simply needed to use the values in `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the trigger runs **BEFORE** INSERT or UPDATE, having it select from the table to get the new values is flawed, because the new values are not there already.

Consider this part of the query:

```
SELECT concat("name", ' ', "phone") as text 
   FROM "Customers" 
   where "id" = NEW.id
```

In the case of an INSERT, you'll always get NULL here and in the case of an UPDATE, you'll get the values that are about to be replaced rather than the new ones.

What should be used as a drop-in replacement for the code above is:

```
SELECT (NEW.name || ' ' || NEW.phone) AS text
```

---

Another point that looks suspicious is: if any of the fields in the user details from any of the 3 tables is NULL, then the whole concatened contents are going to be empty, because the code applies `coalesce` at the very end instead of doing it on each individual field.

Comment: Yeah... I feel a bit sheepish.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking my approach is not good. I've asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869891/a-better-way-to-munge-searchable-text-into-tsvector-column